# Request.Files.Count always 0 when using an input of type file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am not able to get the uploaded file, it always shows Request.Files.Count as 0.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("HandleForm", "Home", new { EncType = "multipart/form-data" }))
{    
    <div>Upload Something: 
        <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" />
    </div>
    <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Controller Action:

```
 public ActionResult HandleForm(HttpPostedFileBase uploadedFile)
        {                
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[0];

                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                }
            }

            return View("FormResults");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object%29) of `BeginForm()` and adding a route value for `enctype`, not a html attribute.

You need to use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod,System.Object%29)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("HandleForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))`
```

Comment: It worked for me but, it would have been helpful if  you have explained it in detail. Without adding the FormMethod.Post, the action method got hit, but only the file was null. So, I thought FormMethod.Post helps only to fire a post request.

Comment: I did explain it. In order to post a file, you need to include the `enctype` attribute - but your code was not adding it - its was adding a route attribute (look at the `action` attribute of your form using your code - its was `action="/Home/HandleForm?enctype=multipart/form-data` - and there was no`enctype` attribute)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you time and comment. Can i do same with @Html.TextBox("uploadedFile", null, new { type = "file" }). In the above example, i used <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" />. If I use @Html.Text, its not showing.

Comment: Your `@Html.TextBox("uploadedFile", null, new { type = "file" })` will work fine (although you really should be using a view model containing a `HttpPostedFileBase UploadedFile` property and using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UploadedFile", new { type = "file" })` and the POST method will be `public ActionResult HandleForm(yourModel model)`)